# I can't run or build a application in flutter (FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.)

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

this is the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.0/gradle-7.2.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.0/gradle-7.2.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i tried reinstalling flutter sdk

Comment: The first of the tried URLs it printed is correct. So something is wrong with downloading. Could be a multitude of things, from a broken Java version without proper truststore, to some proxy or firewall blocking the download. Further up in the output, or maybe with `--info` or `--debug` and eventually with a build `--scan` you can maybe get more information, especially if it is because of the truststore.